# How to import Base64 PublicKey via WebCrypto "importKey" in ReactJS script?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webcrypto-api, ecdh

I'm trying to import a Base64 PublicKey using the Web Crypto API function importKey. The purpose is to create a simple modal for parsing a PublicKey and enabling the encryption of a password.

I've tried to import the PublicKey as a Uint8Array using the "raw" method for the importKey function - see below script:

```
import buffer from 'buffer'

let kpub = "U6uvqoxXGj17tFS5C05tSWohDQl2u1ugiHyNKXB9WF0UiYaxa5FxiLX/LxGeDUPMyLmWBGBUjpTzh1owF9RWug=="
let buff = new Buffer(kpub, 'base64');  

window.crypto.subtle.importKey(
  "raw",  
  buff,
  {    
      name: "ECDH",
      namedCurve: "P-256", 
  },
  false,  
  []  
)
.then(function(publicKey){
  console.log(publicKey);
})
.catch(function(err){
  console.error(err);
});
```

I expected this to produce the imported version of the input, kpub. However, the output is not shown in the console - and when the error handling is enabled, I get a DOMException instead.

Any idea what part I'm doing wrong?

As an alternative, it might be easier to convert the publicKey into the JWK format. As an example, I've confirmed that the below JWK works as intended in the importKey function. However, if I'm to use this I struggle with how to convert my input kpub to the x and y coordinates:

```
const jwkKey = {
  "kty":"EC",
  "crv":"P-256",
  "x":"f83OJ3D2xF1Bg8vub9tLe1gHMzV76e8Tus9uPHvRVEU",
  "y":"x_FEzRu9m36HLN_tue659LNpXW6pCyStikYjKIWI5a0",
  "kid":"Id that can be uniquely Identified"
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some help from Dmitry Chestnykh, I got it working by prepending a single byte, 0x04:

```
const device_kpub_base64 = "U6uvqoxXGj17tFS5C05tSWohDQl2u1ugiHyNKXB9WF0UiYaxa5FxiLX/LxGeDUPMyLmWBGBUjpTzh1owF9RWug=="
const prepend_byte = new Buffer([4])
let device_kpub_buffer = new Buffer(device_kpub_base64, 'base64');  
device_kpub_buffer = Buffer.concat([prepend_byte, device_kpub_buffer])

// Import the device public key into the web crypto API
window.crypto.subtle.importKey(
  "raw",  
  device_kpub_buffer,
  {    
      name: "ECDH",
      namedCurve: "P-256", 
  },
  true,  
  []  
)
.then(function(devicePublicKey){
  console.log(devicePublicKey);
})
.catch(function(err){
  console.error(err);
});
```